# How to remove/cancel my edit after it has been accepted?

Tags: support, questions, edits, cancel

I just edited someone's question. He accepted/confirmed my edit. But now I realize that my edit is wrong. How can I undo this accepted edit?

Comment: can we have a link to the question? We can roll it back.

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824696/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected

Comment: @HugoDozois do you work at SO? if no, which user can 'roll it back'? with big reputation or what? thanks.

Comment: I do think your edit is correct. It's written unexpected `<` but you removed 2 `>` (which were probably used for formatting and not causing the error.) But if you want I can roll it back

Comment: At 2k rep you can do a rollback to a previous edit

Comment: owh.. thanks, yes please roll it back if you dont mind. Thanks, many thanks.

Comment: Well, after the rollback someone formatted the question again, then the OP added more code and the formatting was removed. So I formatted it again. But it may eventually get deleted.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to undo an edit is to either:

1. Edit it again and undo your changes manually (make sure you explain what you're doing!)
2. Ask someone else to do it for you.  At [2000 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) users can edit posts and rollback edits.

The best way to ask someone else is in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).  I don't recommend creating a meta question every time this happens.